# I try to recover a state in store (react, redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm a beginner with react and redux.

I came to create a store provider and a reducer. the value changes in the store when I dispatch.

but I cannot display this value in my compenent. I must not understand something.

[compenent](https://github.com/coockieHunt/ck_rp-developpement-/blob/master/view/src/js/compenents/TestCompenent.jsx)

[reducer](https://github.com/coockieHunt/ck_rp-developpement-/blob/master/view/src/js/reducers/test.jsx)

[store](https://github.com/coockieHunt/ck_rp-developpement-/blob/master/view/src/js/store.jsx)

[index](https://github.com/coockieHunt/ck_rp-developpement-/blob/master/view/src/js/index.jsx)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can install the redux devtool extension on your browser to see how your state changes based on your dispatched actions.

Comment: If you're a beginner with React, _do not_ start with Redux. You probably won't need Redux at all.

Comment: the redux devtool and already installed but this one does not help me: /

I studied the question well, if I need redux. and I am not the choice given the usefulness of my project.

Comment: HI!  Welcome to stackoverflow.  I hope you're able to find the help you need here.  It is totally appropriate to paste the code here using codeblocks and markdown.  See (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) if you need help with that.  Links tend to get broken and so it's better to create a minimum example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people reading the question can better understand and help solve the problem.

Comment: A minor issue with the code I see here is that the code mis-spells the word "Component" in several places.  It's going to make the project a lot more readable and easy to maintain if the spelling is changed from "Compenent" to "Component".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers#combinereducersreducers) takes all the reducers you provide it, and flattens it into a single object. In order to do this effectively, it namespaces each state slice based on the key you provide it. When you use `mapStateToProps`, you need to lookup the state based on that key, in your case `TestReducer`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  valueTest: state.TestReducer.content,
});
```

It's common to namespace your reducers to make future `mapStateToProps` code easier to read/maintain. In your case, that might look something like this:

store

```
export const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      test: TestReducer,
    },
));
```

mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  valueTest: state.test.content,
});
```